# Python Selenium select element a few questions

Tags: python, selenium, element

I have two questions.

1. I'm trying to get the text value (Medium Coverage, Liquid Formula) But there are no locators. These text values are different from pages but the locations are the same. Is there any way to get this text like

```
find_element_by_class('css_s6sd4y.eanm7710') -> go down to one more row then select the element
```

[image]

2. There is a class name. But I wonder if there is another way to find the element using data-at = 'sku_size_label'. And what is 'data-at' locator called?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for first question, you can use the below code :

**to get the Medium Coverage :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Medium Coverage']/.."))).text
print(ele)
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Medium Coverage']/.."))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(ele)
```

**to get the Liquid Formula :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Liquid Formula']/.."))).text
print(ele)
```

or

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Liquid Formula']/.."))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
 print(ele)
```

for your second question :-

Yes you can use `data-at = 'sku_size_label'` in xpath or css :

**Xpath below :**

```
//span[contains(@data-at, 'sku_size_label')]
```

**CSS below :**

```
span[data-at = 'sku_size_label']
```

and for this question :

what is `'data-at' locator called?` - They are not called locators, they are basically attributes of the respective tag.

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: for the first question, is there any way to achieve the same thing using the following logic?

`find_element_by_class('css_s6sd4y.eanm7710') -> go down to one more row then select the element`


Because I need to get the text info in multiple web pages. Even though the format is the same, the text is different.

Comment: you can try with `find_element_by_css_selector("css_s6sd4y.eanm7710"), you cannot combine class name with `.`, it has to css